# Passing a variable from text box to a API url for Digital Ocean

Tags: php, api, digital-ocean

I’m trying to get the URL below to change the hostname of a server with Digital Oceans API

```
<a href=\"https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/$serverid/rename/?client_id=$myClientID&api_key=$myDOApi&name=newHostName\" target=\"_blank\">
<font color=\"#CCFB5D\">Rename</font></a>
```

This link works perfectly if I manually type the new hostname in the code, but how would I pass a `newHostName` variable from a text box into the url with PHP as it is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code as presented:

```
<a href=\"https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/$serverid/rename/?client_id=$myClientID&api_key=$myDOApi&name=newHostName\" target=\"_blank\">
<font color=\"#CCFB5D\">Rename</font></a>
```

But then you say:

```
…but how would I pass a newHostName variable from a text box into the url with PHP as it is submitted?
```

Why not just make a URL like this and set `$newHostName` as a variable `$newHostName`?

```
https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/$serverid/rename/?client_id=$myClientID&api_key=$myDOApi&name=$newHostName
```

But your code is lacking. Why are the double-quotes escaped like this `\"`? You have a PHP tag but where is the actual PHP? Is it already a part of a larger string that has double-quotes already in place?

Assuming good faith, why can’t your code—as presented—be like this instead?

```
echo '<a href="https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/' . $serverid . '/rename/?client_id=' . $myClientID . '&api_key=' . $myDOApi . '&name=' . $newHostName . '" target="_blank">
<font color="#CCFB5D">Rename</font></a>';
```

Or perhaps use `sprintf` to make things more readable:

```
echo sprintf('<a href="https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/%s/rename/?client_id=%s&api_key=%s&name=%s" target="_blank">', $serverid, $myClientID, $myDOApi, $newHostName)
   . '<font color="#CCFB5D">Rename</font></a>'
   ;
```

Comment: the code is straight from the Digital Ocean Api to rename a droplet, its not something I've created. how do i get the value for $newHostName variable it to the url from a text box

Comment: sorry, code is from here https://www.digi77.com/make-use-of-digital-ocean-vps-api-with-php-wrapper/